# Convención Java para ordenar métodos

Tags: java

¿Hay una **convención en Java** que indique como deben ordenarse los métodos o es algo libre a gusto del programador?

Me refiero a que considero una buena práctica ordenar los métodos en grupos por visibilidad y dentro de estos en orden alfabético, de cara a localizarlos con facilidad. No se si Java dice algo al respecto porque he visto que **los *getters* y *setters* se agrupan en parejas para cada propiedad** y esto rompe mi esquema. Entonces, no se si ésto es la norma o es libre, porque *Netbeans*, *AndroidStudio* y otros *IDEs* lo hacen cuando se generan estos métodos automáticamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, no hay ningún orden. Puedes consultar [las convenciones oficiales de Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)(en inglés); no hay ninguna referencia a ordenación de métodos.

   No obstante lo anterior, veo que se usa más agrupar getters y setters por pares. Una ventaja es que, cuando añades una propiedad, no tienes que saltar de parte a parte para añadir getter y setter.
2. Por lo anterior, en general no pasa nada si no usas el mismo orden. De todas formas, suele ser útil ser coherente (contigo mismo y con la organización con la que trabajas).
3. En cualquier IDE medianamente avanzada podrás configurar muchos detalles del código generado, por ejemplo en Eclipse:

[image: Generación de código en Eclipse]

4. Y, por supuesto, no sólo todos los IDE te permiten hacer búsquedas (por texto, o ir directamte a la declaración de un método, o encontrar todos los sitios de donde es llamado), sino que también te permiten visualizar sus propiedades y métodos como prefieras; en Eclipse:

[image: Vista de Outline en Eclipse]

**TL;DR** No hay regla oficial, pero lo más normal es agrupar por atributo. En todo caso lo más importante es ser coherente, sobre todo si estás en una organización. Los IDEs suelen dar posibilidades para a) generar el código cómo deseas y b) encontrar lo que buscas sin que necesites que el código esté ordenado de una manera determinada.